# Unable to authenticate using Kerberos Keytab and kinit cache

Tags: ldap, kerberos, keytab

I am using a keytab and setting it up using the kinit command on my windows commandline. I get the message "New ticket is stored in cache file".After that when I run my java application to access the keytab file for the key I get below error.

```
Authentication attempt failed javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No key to store
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No key to store
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.commit(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

I am trying to connect to the active directory using ldap. Below are the configuration settings:

```
-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\Users\cXXXXXX\Git\gssapi_jaas.conf
-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true
```

Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache true useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is

C:\Users\cXXXXXX\Git\abcd.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is xxxx_dev@xxxx.xxxxxx.COM tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
    Acquire TGT from Cache

> > > KinitOptions cache name is C:\Users\cXXXXXX\krb5cc_cXXXXXX
> > >       DEBUG   client principal is xxxx_dev@xxxx.xxxxxx.COM
> > >       DEBUG  server principal is krbtgt/xxxx.xxxxxx.COM@Txxxx.xxxxxx.COM
> > >       DEBUG  key type: 23
> > >       DEBUG  auth time: Mon Jul 01 14:20:21 EDT 2019
> > >       DEBUG  start time: Mon Jul 01 14:20:21 EDT 2019
> > >       DEBUG  end time: Tue Jul 02 00:20:21 EDT 2019
> > >       DEBUG  renew_till time: null
> > >       CCacheInputStream: readFlags()  INITIAL; PRE_AUTH;
> > >           Host address is /xx.xx.xxx.xx
> > >           Host address is /xxx:0:0:0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
> > >       KrbCreds found the default ticket granting ticket in credential cache.
> > >           Java config name: null
> > >           Native config name: C:\windows\krb5.ini
> > >       Obtained TGT from LSA: Credentials:
> > >                 client=sxxxx_dev@xxxx.xxxxxx.COM
> > >                 server=krbtgt/Txxxx.xxxxxx.COM@Txxxx.xxxxxx.COM
> > >               authTime=20190701182021Z
> > >              startTime=20190701182021Z
> > >                endTime=20190702042021Z
> > >              renewTill=null
> > >                  flags=INITIAL;PRE-AUTHENT
> > >           EType (skey)=23
> > >              (tkt key)=18
> > >           Principal is sxxxx_dev@xxxx.xxxxxx.COM

Before adding the kinit cache fil, I was able to atleast validate the account, then I was having issues with GSSapi security. Trying to resolve that I added the cache and this new problem started to happen

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // 1. Log in (to Kerberos)
    LoginContext lc = null;
    try {
        /*lc = new LoginContext(Azrm017.class.getName(),
        new LuwCallBackHandler());
*/
        lc = new LoginContext("Azrm017");
        // Attempt authentication
        // You might want to do this in a "for" loop to give
        // user more than one chance to enter correct username/password
        lc.login();

    } catch (LoginException le) {
        System.err.println("Authentication attempt failed " + le);
        le.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Authentication attempt failed " + le.getSuppressed());

        System.exit(-1);
    }

    // 2. Perform JNDI work as logged in subject
    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> ne =
            (NamingEnumeration<SearchResult>) Subject.doAs(lc.getSubject(),
                new SearchAction());
    while(ne.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println(">>>> : " + ne.nextElement().getName());
    }

    //Subject.doAs(lc.getSubject(), new JndiAction(args));
    }
}


/**
 * The application must supply a PrivilegedAction that is to be run
 * inside a Subject.doAs() or Subject.doAsPrivileged().
 */
class SearchAction implements java.security.PrivilegedAction {

    public Object run() {

        // Set up the environment for creating the initial context
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<> (11);
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        String cn = "dn:CN=xxxxxxx,OU=Service xxxxx,OU=Accounts,OU=xxxxx,DC=test,DC=xxxxxx,DC=com";
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://test.xxxxxxx.com:389");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "GSSAPI");
        env.put("javax.security.sasl.server.authentication", "true");
        env.put("javax.security.sasl.qop", "auth-conf");

        DirContext ctx = null;
        try {
           // Create initial context
           ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

           SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
           ctls.setReturningAttributes(
                 new String[] {"displayName", "mail","description", "suSunetID"});

           NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer =
                ctx.search("cn=People, dc=test, dc=xxxxxxxx, dc=com",
                                 "(&(cn=p*)(sn=s*))", ctls);

            return answer;


        } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
         // Close the context when we're done
        finally {
            closeContext(ctx);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Attached above

Comment: hi anyone has a answer for my question?

Answer (score 0):

This is a wrong combination of Krb5LoginModule options. If you want an initiator to store a key then that key must be used to acquire the ticket (i.e. useTicketCache should not be true).

Why do you want to store the key? Will the initiator also act as an acceptor? If yes, you should either use the keytab to authenticate (i.e. useTicketCache=false) or go with the ENC-TKT-IN-SKEY way (i.e. storeKey=false).